# C#: How to write special characters to ADLDS?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, ldap, adlds

I'm trying to write contacts into an ADLDS ldap for using them as a phone book for a Yealink T48G. Sometimes the name of the contact includes some special characters like "ö", "ß" and "é". If these characters are contained in the fields "givenName" or "displayName" neither the phone nor the ldap client can show them correctly and instead show some other chars (for example "ö" -> "Ã¶"), however the "name" and "dn" fields show these characters correctly.

If I insert the contactvalues via ADSI-Edit or any other tool, the phone shows the name correctly, but my application is no longer able to read the inserted special chars from givenName and shows some questionmark-boxes, however the dn and name fields are read correctly.

I've already tried using utf-8, utf-16, utf-32, iso-8859-1 and windows-1252 as encoding for my application.

So the question is how can I store these special characters using C# in the givenName property for an inetOrgPerson in an ADLDS instance?

shown correctly:

[image: Corret special characters]

shown incorrectly:

[image: Incorrect special characters]

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.Net;

namespace LdapContacts
{    
    public class LdapClient
    {
        private LdapConnection connection;

        public LdapClient(string host, int port, string distinguishedUsername, string password)
        {
            connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(host, port));
            connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
            connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(distinguishedUsername, password);
            connection.Bind();
        }

        public AddResponse SendAddRequest(string distinguishedName, List<DirectoryAttribute> attributes)
        {
            AddRequest request = new AddRequest(distinguishedName, attributes.ToArray());
            return connection.SendRequest(request) as AddResponse;
        }

        public SearchResponse SendSearchRequest(string distinguishedName, string filter)
        {
            SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
            request.DistinguishedName = distinguishedName;
            request.Filter = filter;
            request.Scope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            return connection.SendRequest(request) as SearchResponse;
        }
    }

    public class ContactsToLdap
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LdapClient client = new LdapClient(Settings.LdapHost, Settings.LdapPort, Settings.LdapUsername, Settings.LdapPassword);

            client.SendAddRequest("CN=Testöäüß,CN=Users,CN=testpart,DC=csdomain,DC=local", new List<DirectoryAttribute>()
            {
                new DirectoryAttribute("telephoneNumber", "0123456"),
                new DirectoryAttribute("objectClass", "inetOrgPerson"),
                new DirectoryAttribute("uid", "io3e"),
                new DirectoryAttribute("givenName", "â é testnameöüÄß")
            });
            //distinguished name of contactsfolder
            SearchResponse result = client.SendSearchRequest(Settings.LdapContactsFolder, "(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)");
            foreach (SearchResultEntry sResult in result.Entries)
            {
                //display the index of the current entry
                Console.Write((result.Entries.IndexOf(sResult) + 1) + ":\n");
                foreach (DirectoryAttribute attribute in sResult.Attributes.Values)
                {
                    //output the name of the attribute
                    Console.Write("\t" + attribute.Name + " = ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < attribute.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // convert the attribute to a string if it is an byte[]
                        // output if inserted with ADSI-Edit: ? ? testname????
                        // output if inserted with this code: â é testnameöüÄß
                        if (attribute[i].GetType().Equals(typeof(byte[])))
                        {
                            Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])attribute[i]) + "; ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write(attribute[i] + "; ");
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by setting the protocolversion that should be used to version 3.

```
connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(host, port));
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
```

Comment: Are the special characters now shown in the Yealink T48G correctly?

Comment: If you set the protocol version in the webinterface of the phone to version 3 then yes.